# Getting product join issue

Tags: teradata

i have one query which is doing a product join because there is join condition missing in the LOJ. Could you guys help me find an alternative to the below:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
1 AS ARRANGEMENT_ID
,AR.ARRANGEMENT_TYPE_ID
,TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM SRC.QCA_KB_ACCT_NBR) AS UNIQUE_ID_IN_SOURCE_SYSTEM
,NULL AS AR_OPEN_DATE
,NULL AS AR_CLOSED_DATE
,NULL AS AR_LCS_DATE
,-3 AS AR_LCS_TYPE_ID
,CPT.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID
,-3 AS SUB_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID
,NULL AS REPRESENTING_ORG_UNIT_ID
,-3 AS AR_BRAND_TYPE_ID
,NULL AS INITIATING_IP_ID
,-3 AS CLOSED_REASON_TYPE_ID
,-3 AS GL_SBU_TYPE_ID
,-3 AS AR_PAYMENT_TYPE_ID
,-3 AS AR_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ID
,SRC.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
,SRC.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
,'ZAF'
,'40' AS FILE_ID
,'' AS ETL_PROCESS_ID
,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) AS DW_LOAD_TIMESTAMP
,NULL AS DW_UPD_LOAD_TIMESTAMP
FROM Y.T_Q18000_ACCOUNT_MASTER_INT SRC 
LEFT OUTER JOIN X.ARRANGEMENT_TYPE AR
ON AR.ARRANGEMENT_TYPE_DESC = 'Account Arrangement'
LEFT OUTER JOIN X.COMBD_PRODUCT_TYPE CPT
ON CPT.ORIGINAL_LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME = 'PRODUCT'
AND CPT.PRODUCT_TYPE_CODE = 'CARD'
AND CPT.PRODUCT_TYPE_DESC = 'Card'
AND CPT.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE = '3499-12-31'
```

It's throwing no more room in database.

Should i go for inline query here. I dont have a joining condition for other table.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this query will return what you want?

Do to the missing join-conditions you actually `CROSS JOIN` all rows from both `ARRANGEMENT_TYPE` and `COMBD_PRODUCT_TYPE` to `T_Q18000_ACCOUNT_MASTER_INT` (and `DISTINCT` seems to cure the effect, but not the cause).

Try to join to Dervied Tables instead:

```
FROM Y.T_Q18000_ACCOUNT_MASTER_INT SRC 
CROSS JOIN 
 (
   SELECT *
   FROM X.ARRANGEMENT_TYPE
   WHERE ARRANGEMENT_TYPE_DESC = 'Account Arrangement'
 ) AS AR
CROSS JOIN
 (
   SELECT * 
   FROM X.COMBD_PRODUCT_TYPE
   WHERE ORIGINAL_LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME = 'PRODUCT'
     AND PRODUCT_TYPE_CODE = 'CARD'
     AND PRODUCT_TYPE_DESC = 'Card'
     AND EFFECTIVE_END_DATE = '3499-12-31'
 ) AS CPT
```

Hopefully those Derived Table return a small number of rows...

If those Selects actually return a single row you might replace them by a Scalar Subquery, this should access both tables with a "Dispatcher Retrieve Step" and a single table scan without any joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT -- distinct probably no longer needed
   1 AS ARRANGEMENT_ID
   , (
       SELECT ARRANGEMENT_TYPE_ID
       FROM X.ARRANGEMENT_TYPE
       WHERE ARRANGEMENT_TYPE_DESC = 'Account Arrangement'
     ) AS ARRANGEMENT_TYPE_ID
   ,TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM SRC.QCA_KB_ACCT_NBR) AS UNIQUE_ID_IN_SOURCE_SYSTEM
   ,NULL AS AR_OPEN_DATE
   ,NULL AS AR_CLOSED_DATE
   ,NULL AS AR_LCS_DATE
   ,-3 AS AR_LCS_TYPE_ID
   , (
       SELECT PRODUCT_TYPE_ID 
       FROM X.COMBD_PRODUCT_TYPE
       WHERE ORIGINAL_LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME = 'PRODUCT'
         AND PRODUCT_TYPE_CODE = 'CARD'
         AND PRODUCT_TYPE_DESC = 'Card'
         AND EFFECTIVE_END_DATE = '3499-12-31'
     ) AS PRODUCT_TYPE_ID
   ,-3 AS SUB_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID
   ,NULL AS REPRESENTING_ORG_UNIT_ID
   ,-3 AS AR_BRAND_TYPE_ID
   ,NULL AS INITIATING_IP_ID
   ,-3 AS CLOSED_REASON_TYPE_ID
   ,-3 AS GL_SBU_TYPE_ID
   ,-3 AS AR_PAYMENT_TYPE_ID
   ,-3 AS AR_STRUCTURE_TYPE_ID
   ,SRC.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
   ,SRC.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
   ,'ZAF'
   ,'40' AS FILE_ID
   ,'' AS ETL_PROCESS_ID
   ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) AS DW_LOAD_TIMESTAMP
   ,NULL AS DW_UPD_LOAD_TIMESTAMP
FROM Y.T_Q18000_ACCOUNT_MASTER_INT AS SRC
```

Comment: Hi Dieter,
Yes, the second join is required as we require results for particular specification of combd_product_type

Comment: @user3901666: I didn't notice that the 2nd join is also a `CROSS JOIN`, you might also need to move it into a Derived Table like the 1st join, I edited my answer.

Comment: Hi Dieter,
Please help me understand how is this going to help. The plan is showing some improvement, but i couldn't understand the reason behind it.

Comment: The Product Join is still happening, but the steps are different and the few spool is created as compared to previous query plan.

Comment: @user3901666: If you join using a `Left Join` you get **all** rows from the outer table even if they can't be joined. In your case you join to the matching rows plus all other rows (returning NULLs), most of those NULL result rows will be duplicate and the final `DISTINCT` removes all but one row per account. Of course this might run out of spool. If you apply the conditions before the join the number of rows is reduced (hopefully down to one). See my edited answer.